# How to fetch the max( latest_modified_time) records from resultsets of two sub-queries for each user using group by clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that fetches list of records. I need to filter these two result sets so that my final result set contains maximum value of  **latest_modified_time** column for each user. How to do that ?

**Query 1 :**

```
select us.user_id as user_id , us.modified_datetime as  latest_modified_time , CONCAT(ui.first_name,' ',ui.last_name) as full_name
from lsa_user_skill us 
left join lsa_user_info ui on  us.modified_user_id=  ui.user_id 
where (us.user_id, us.modified_datetime ) IN 
             (select  us.user_id, MAX(us.modified_datetime) from lsa_user_skill us group by  us.user_id) ;
```

**Query 2 :**

```
select  sal.affected_user_id  as user_id, sal.modified_timestamp as latest_modified_time , CONCAT(info1.first_name,' ', info1.last_name) as full_name 
 from lsa_skill_auditlog sal
 left join lsa_user_info info on info.user_id=sal.affected_user_id 
 left join lsa_user_info info1 on info1.user_id=sal.user_id 
 where sal.activity = 'User skill deleted';
```

As below mentioned, I tried with **UNION function** which gives sum of result set of those two queries. But, not getting how to group by user_id to fetch records that contains max(lates_modified_time)  for each user ?

**Query Tried is :**

```
select us.user_id as user_id , us.modified_datetime as  latest_modified_time , CONCAT(ui.first_name,' ',ui.last_name) as full from lsa_user_skill us 
             left join lsa_user_info ui on  us.modified_user_id=  ui.user_id 
         where (us.user_id, us.modified_datetime ) IN 
             (select  us.user_id, MAX(us.modified_datetime) from lsa_user_skill us group by  us.user_id)
UNION
select  sal.affected_user_id  as user_id, sal.modified_timestamp as latest_modified_time , CONCAT(info1.first_name,' ', info1.last_name) as full from lsa_skill_auditlog sal
 left join lsa_user_info info on info.user_id=sal.affected_user_id 
 left join lsa_user_info info1 on info1.user_id=sal.user_id 
 where sal.activity = 'User skill deleted'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union` and `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id), x.*
from ((select us.user_id as user_id , us.modified_datetime as  latest_modified_time , CONCAT(ui.first_name, ' ', ui.last_name) as full_name
       from lsa_user_skill us left join
            lsa_user_info ui
            on us.modified_user_id = ui.user_id 
      ) union all
      (select sal.affected_user_id  as user_id, sal.modified_timestamp as latest_modified_time, CONCAT(info1.first_name, ' ', info1.last_name) as full_name 
       from lsa_skill_auditlog sal left join
            lsa_user_info info
            on info.user_id = sal.affected_user_id left join
            lsa_user_info info1
            on info1.user_id = sal.user_id 
       where sal.activity = 'User skill deleted'
      )
     ) x
order by user_id, latest_modified_time desc;
```

Comment: The bad grammar in the question leaves it open whether *all* records with maximal `latest_modified_time` are desired or only one. Your solution covers the latter case.

Comment: @Karthiksa . . . If this works, why didn't you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as a subselect, have an outer query using `rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY latest_modified_time DESC)` and another outer query that selects only those rows where the rank is 1.

This will give you *all* records for each user where `latest_modified_time` is maximal.

```
SELECT user_id,
       latest_modified_time,
       full_name
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             latest_modified_time,
             full_name,
             rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY latest_modified_time DESC)
      FROM (SELECT us.user_id AS user_id,
                   us.modified_datetime AS latest_modified_time,
                   CONCAT(ui.first_name, ' ', ui.last_name) AS full_name
            FROM lsa_user_skill AS us 
               LEFT JOIN lsa_user_info AS ui ON us.modified_user_id = ui.user_id
            WHERE (us.user_id, us.modified_datetime) IN
                  (SELECT us.user_id, MAX(us.modified_datetime)
                   FROM lsa_user_skill AS us
                   GROUP BY us.user_id)
            UNION
            SELECT sal.affected_user_id AS user_id,
                   sal.modified_timestamp AS latest_modified_time,
                   CONCAT(info1.first_name, ' ', info1.last_name) AS full_name
            FROM lsa_skill_auditlog AS sal
               LEFT JOIN lsa_user_info AS info ON info.user_id = sal.affected_user_id
               LEFT JOIN lsa_user_info AS info1 ON info1.user_id = sal.user_id 
            WHERE sal.activity = 'User skill deleted'
           ) AS v_union
     ) AS v_ordered
WHERE rank = 1;
```